# Starting Cassandra on the foreground

Tags: cassandra

If I start the Cassandra service everything is ok, but when I try to start Cassandra on the foreground using "cassandra -f" I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra.logs.gc.log

Do I need to configure anything in particular to run Cassandra in the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the space in your "Program Files" directory is not escaped in your CASSANDRA_HOME environment variable. It gets set in your [cassandra-env.ps1](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/87d80b478bd47770460ecf7a8713e00d2f53fcca/conf/cassandra-env.ps1#L337) (in conf/) config file, you could manually set it.

Comment: I have my CASSANDRA_HOME var set to 'C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\'
I have also set the $env:JVM_OPTS="$env:JVM_OPTS -Xloggc:$env:C:/Program Files/DataStax-DDC/apache-cassandra/logs/gc.log" on the cassandra-env.ps1
I have also created the folder "logs" which did not existed. But I keep getting the same error :(

Comment: try using `Program\ Files`. I dont run windows so I cant test it, the problem is the space in the path

Comment: No idea why it was not working, but got tired of it and installed Cassandra on the root folder. Solved :)